# Accessing Data in Object over http put request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, router

I have a react front end using axios to send a http request of a object stored in state to a NodeJS rest api service. Im having issues using the object in the nodejs side.

React Put

```
    submit = () => {
        this.setState({ questionnaire_completed: true })
        console.log("user" + this.state.user);
        let url_ =  process.env.REACT_APP_USER_RESTAPI + "/user_psychometrics/questionnaire?authtoken="+process.env.REACT_APP_USER_RESTAPI_KEY+"&username=" + this.state.user + "&results=" + this.state.questions
        console.log("url: ", url_)
        axios.put(url_).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

Code inside the router.put on node.

```
let user_answers = util.inspect(req.query.results, {showHidden: true, depth: null})
console.log("UA: ", user_answers)

let user_answ_keys = Object.keys(req.query.results)
console.log("uak", user_answ_keys)
user_answ_keys.forEach(function(item){
console.log(req.query.results[item])
})
```

Console.log screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBF57.jpg

Comment: looks  like your `req.query.results[item]` is also an object, try to use JSON.stringify your req.query.results so you can have better view of the results object

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that `this.state.questions` is an `Array`, something like:

```
[ '1', '2', '3', ....., 'n']
```

or whatever similar,so what you are missing when sending the array over the query parameter is to stringify it, so you should do:

```
let url_ =  process.env.REACT_APP_USER_RESTAPI + "/user_psychometrics/questionnaire?authtoken="+process.env.REACT_APP_USER_RESTAPI_KEY+"&username=" + this.state.user + "&results=" + JSON.stringify(this.state.questions)
```

take as an example the following:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5]
const badUrl = '/foo/bar?questions='+array
const goodUrl = '/foo/bar?questions='+JSON.stringify(array)

console.log({badUrl, goodUrl})
```

as you can see, `/foo/bar?questions=1,2,3,4,5` is not correct.

with this your problem should be solved, another thing to notice is if your `util.inspect(req.query.results, {showHidden: true, depth: null})` is already parsing this array, any other way you should change it to:

`util.inspect(JSON.parse(req.query.results), {showHidden: true, depth: null})`

note: if you array is not `[ '1', '2', '3', ....., 'n']` doesn't matter, this solution should work anyways.